# How do I POST a Javascript array and use it with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Right so I've been trying to pass a variable from Javascript to PHP but I haven't been able to do that. Looking at the network panel I can see that the variable is being POSTed but it's just the PHP that is not recieving it.

PHP & HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tagsArray.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['items'])) {
        $items = $_POST['items'];
        echo "Items received: $items";
    } else {
        echo "Items not received.";
    }
?>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var arrayItems = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

$.ajax({
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("AJAX request successful:", response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("AJAX request error:", error);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'testjs.php',
    data: { items: arrayItems }, 
    success: function() { console.log("Sent");
    }
});
```

I keep getting `Items not recieved.`.

Comment: Is `testjs.php` the page that contains the HTML listed above?  On your PHP page what do you get if you simply have `echo var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: I would guess you are posting the ajax to the same php script which contains the JS and is also loaded into your browser? If so you're probably seeing what php outputs when the page is first loaded, rather than as the result of the ajax request. This is a surprisingly common logical mistake that people make. Your JS never tries to output the ajax results to the page! In the Network tool, click on the POST request and look at the Response tab to see what php returned in response to the POST request specifically.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Yes testjs.php contains the HTML, `array(0) { }` is being returned when I have `echo var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @ADyson Oh wow when I use, `echo var_dump($_POST);` and check the response it's returning:

`array(1) {
  ["items"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "item1"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "item2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "item3"
  }
}`

Comment: You might want to spell received right.

Comment: @Crimin4L no that will make the problem worse.  You can see from the OP's last comment that the data is being received correctly once they look in the right place

Comment: @Wintah OK so now you need to make your JS code in the "success" function read the response and output it onto the page somewhere. P.s. var_dump doesn't require an echo, it outputs automatically